# This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: Project `my-ci-test-group/test-yaml` not found or access denied! even though they are in the same group

Tags: gitlab-ci

Im trying to access a gitlab yaml from another project in my main project.
Is there a setting i have to change so they can access each other?

```
Code:

include:
  - project: 'my-ci-test-group/test-yaml'
    file: '.gitlab-ci.yml'
```

I keep getting:

This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: Project `my-ci-test-group/test-yaml` not found or access denied!

They are both in the same group, shouldnt they be able to access each other?
Im also owner of both projects/repos.

Comment: Do you have developer or maintainer access in the repo my-ci-test-group/test-yaml?

Comment: @danielnelz Im owner of both repos

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, it turns out the group name that was displayed wasnt the group name that needed to be linked.

so it had to be

```
include:


- project: 'my-ci-test-group123/test-yaml'
    file: '.gitlab-ci.yml'
```